# Convert string of dd-MON-yy to date in Python

Tags: python, strptime

I have a string in dd-MON-yy format. While converting to date in python, its is causing issue since the year is in tow digits.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('17-JUN-03', '%d-%m-%y')
```

The error is,

```
ValueError: time data '17-JUN-03' does not match format '%d-%m-%y'
```

Comment: The problem is not with the year, it's with the month

Comment: Don't use such a format. The year is a serious problem all right, just not the source of the exception. *NOTHING* says this is 1903 or 2003 except wild assumptions. Never mind that only assumptions say that this is 2003 instead of 2017. This has resulted in some serious (and quite funny) outages . Before COVID the big IT news was Lloyd's outage due to such data: [Y2K? How about Y2.02K as Lloyds suffers its second TITSUP* of the year](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/)

Comment: @Flimm the year is an even bigger problem

Comment: Also [Y2K quick-fix crick? 1920s come roaring back after mystery blip at UK's vehicle licensing agency](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/13/y2k_dvla/) . In the US [Y2K20? A Few Systems Aren't Handling the New Year Very Well](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/y2k20-a-few-systems-arent-handling-the-new-year-very-wellhttps://www.tomshardware.com/news/y2k20-a-few-systems-arent-handling-the-new-year-very-well)

Comment: You're all right, having a two-digit year is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('17-JUN-03', '%d-%b-%y'))
```

Result:

```
2003-06-17 00:00:00
```

[Datetime format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: Assuming the year is 2003 is very unsafe and the source of quite a few outages in the last couple of years

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm merely sticking the OP's question and as he wrote the format should be: *I have a string in dd-MON-yy format*

Comment: Unless it's actually 2017. Before COVID, the big IT news was [Y2K? How about Y2.02K as Lloyds suffers its second TITSUP* of the year](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/)

Comment: In any case the OP failed to specify what the actual year is supposed to be. It's `string in dd-MON-yy` but that doesn't say what year it's supposed to be

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see the issue, you are correct.

Comment: This depends on your locale settings, so if I were you, I would test all twelve months to check that this works as intended.

Comment: @Flimm While this is correct, I can only work with the data provided by OP. :)